# Try/Except for loop using PyAutoGui locateCenter function

Tags: python, image, loops, pyautogui

This code is supposed to execute through 6 iterations of the for loop / technically 3 iterations due to double increment. Instead, I receive an error.

If the rest of the code is required please comment.

Any criticism on my code is appreciated also, any recommendations would be helpful.

My code:

```
import pyautogui
import time
import random
import keyboard
import sys



def findClickShaftFunction():
    count = 1
    v = 1.0

movementTime = random.uniform(0.24, 1.88)
timeToSleep = random.uniform(25.32, 62.5)    

for count in range (0,5):
    try:
        print("Try:", count, " Sample:", count, " Image:", count)
        pictureOfShaftsX, pictureOfShaftsY = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('C:/Users/PyAutoGui_ImageRecognition/shafts{}.png'.format(count), confidence=v)            
    except TypeError:
        continue
        print("Try:", count+1, " Sample:", count+1, " Image:", count+1)
        pictureOfShaftsX, pictureOfShaftsY = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('C:/Users/PyAutoGui_ImageRecognition/shafts{}.png'.format(count+1), confidence=v - 0.10)                      
    #else:
        #count = count + 1  
        #print("Unable to trace " + count)


time.sleep(timeToSleep)

pictureOfShaftsX = pictureOfShaftsX - (random.randint(2,11))
pictureOfShaftsY = pictureOfShaftsY - (random.randint(2,11))
pyautogui.moveTo(pictureOfShaftsX, pictureOfShaftsY, movementTime)
pyautogui.click()
```

Full Error Traceback:

```
       Would you like to begin? Enter y to continue. y
       Try: 0  Sample: 0  Image: 0
       Try: 1  Sample: 1  Image: 1
       Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\PyAutoGui_Shaft_Trial\PyAutoGui_Shaft_Trial\PyAutoGui_Shaft_Trial.py", line 17, in findClickShaftFunction
    pictureOfShaftsX, pictureOfShaftsY = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('C:/Users/PyAutoGui_ImageRecognition/shafts{}.png'.format(count), confidence=v)
       TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

       During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

       Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Users\PyAutoGui_Shaft_Trial\PyAutoGui_Shaft_Trial\PyAutoGui_Shaft_Trial.py", line 78, in <module>
    main()
          File "C:\Users\PyAutoGui_Shaft_Trial\PyAutoGui_Shaft_Trial\PyAutoGui_Shaft_Trial.py", line 56, in main
    findClickShaftFunction()
          File "C:\Users\PyAutoGui_Shaft_Trial\PyAutoGui_Shaft_Trial\PyAutoGui_Shaft_Trial.py", line 20, in findClickShaftFunction
    pictureOfShaftsX, pictureOfShaftsY = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('C:/Users/PyAutoGui_ImageRecognition/shafts{}.png'.format(count+1), confidence=v - 0.10)
         TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
         Press any key to continue . . .
```

After changing

```
except TypeError:
        print("Try:", count+1, " Sample:", count+1, " Image:", count+1)
        pictureOfShaftsX, pictureOfShaftsY = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('C:/Users/PyAutoGui_ImageRecognition/shafts{}.png'.format(count+1), confidence=v - 0.10)
```

To

```
 except TypeError:
         continue
```

It iterates through the whole loop before actually targeting the image.

```
Would you like to begin? Enter y to continue. y
Try: 0  Sample: 0  Image: 0
Try: 1  Sample: 1  Image: 1
Try: 2  Sample: 2  Image: 2
Try: 3  Sample: 3  Image: 3
Try: 4  Sample: 4  Image: 4
Try: 5  Sample: 5  Image: 5
Try: 0  Sample: 0  Image: 0
Try: 1  Sample: 1  Image: 1
Try: 2  Sample: 2  Image: 2
Try: 3  Sample: 3  Image: 3
Try: 4  Sample: 4  Image: 4
Try: 5  Sample: 5  Image: 5
Try: 0  Sample: 0  Image: 0
Try: 1  Sample: 1  Image: 1
Try: 2  Sample: 2  Image: 2
Try: 3  Sample: 3  Image: 3
Try: 4  Sample: 4  Image: 4
Try: 5  Sample: 5  Image: 5
Try: 0  Sample: 0  Image: 0
Try: 1  Sample: 1  Image: 1
Try: 2  Sample: 2  Image: 2
Try: 3  Sample: 3  Image: 3
Try: 4  Sample: 4  Image: 4
Try: 5  Sample: 5  Image: 5
Try: 0  Sample: 0  Image: 0
Try: 1  Sample: 1  Image: 1
Try: 2  Sample: 2  Image: 2
Try: 3  Sample: 3  Image: 3
Try: 4  Sample: 4  Image: 4
Try: 5  Sample: 5  Image: 5
Try: 0  Sample: 0  Image: 0
Try: 1  Sample: 1  Image: 1
Try: 2  Sample: 2  Image: 2
Try: 3  Sample: 3  Image: 3
Try: 4  Sample: 4  Image: 4
Try: 5  Sample: 5  Image: 5
```

An example of what I intend for the loop to do (without the print statement)

```
    try:
        pictureOfShaftsX, pictureOfShaftsY = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('C:/Users/PyAutoGui_ImageRecognition/shafts0.png', confidence=0.7)      
    except TypeError:
        pictureOfShaftsX, pictureOfShaftsY = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('C:/Users/PyAutoGui_ImageRecognition/shafts1.png', confidence=0.6)
        try:
            pictureOfShaftsX, pictureOfShaftsY = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('C:/Users/PyAutoGui_ImageRecognition/shafts2.png', confidence=0.55)      
        except TyperError:
            pictureOfShaftsX, pictureOfShaftsY = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('C:/Users/PyAutoGui_ImageRecognition/shafts3.png', confidence=0.50)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, `pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen` is returning `None`, which is why you get the `TypeError`. Rather than calling that same method in the `except` block, you probably just want to `continue` to the next iteration of the loop, like this:

```
for count in range(6):
    try:
        print("Try:", count, " Sample:", count, " Image:", count)
        pictureOfShaftsX, pictureOfShaftsY = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('C:/Users/PyAutoGui_ImageRecognition/shafts{}.png'.format(count), confidence=v)
    except TypeError:
        continue
```

Also, note that `range(1,6)` goes from 1-5 inclusive - you probably want `range(6)` for 0-5 inclusive (6 iterations total).

Comment: Wow, all I had to do was change my type error statement to continue the loop. This works as far as I can tell. Thank you! - As far as the change to the range, I am aware of this, I was going to edit later. At this point changing it would affect the programs ability to target the image files.

Comment: "it would recognize the images" -- are you sure? What makes you think that? Can you, e.g., print out `pictureOfShaftsX`?

Comment: Ok, so now it iterates through all of the 5 images, I have edited the photo names. The problem is it is only matching up with the last image every time. I have edited 5 screenshots only one is matching. When I did multiple try/except statements without the for loop it would recognize the images after only 1-3 iterations

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking this is a reasonable answer to my question. It seems to iterate as intended - checking each image. Now, I've come to realize TensorFlow may have been better for my application.

Any further advice would be appreciated.

```
    count = 0;
    v = 0.55
    
    movementTime = random.uniform(0.24, 1.88)
    timeToSleep = random.uniform(25.32, 62.5)    
    success = False

    while not success:
        try:
            print("Try:", count, " Sample:", count, " Image:", count)
            pictureOfShaftsX, pictureOfShaftsY = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('C:/Users/PyAutoGui_ImageRecognition/shafts{}.png'.format(count), confidence=v)
            success = True
        except TypeError:
            count = count + 1           
            pass
```